# Places Autocomplete: Must I use a Google map if I Geocode the result with Apple?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

Trying to implement a search feature for USA cities in my IOS app. My goal is to use Google's Autocomplete API while legally avoiding the use of a Google map.

So, if I use Places Autocomplete API to display a list of suggested cities as the user types do I have to use a Google map if I geocode the chosen autocomplete result through apple with CLGeocoder?

Google says you must use their data in their maps. However, if I geocode through Apple to retrieve the coordinates for display on a map, the map data isn't coming from Google. Is this legal?

I know Airbnb uses Googles places api but they use Apple maps.

Comment: the chosen autocomplete result already has its geolocation information prepopulated by google, so you're not really bypassing it. You're just doing it twice. Anyway, we're coders, not lawyers. Anything we could comment on your question would be opinion based, and would stand no grounds against google's own (even if obscure) edge case TOS.

Comment: @amenadiel true but the coordinates are not shown in googles autocomplete results. You have to call the API using the placeid.

Comment: I'm on your side, it's just that there's enough grounds for google to claim you're violating the TOS in the unlikely case they could ever go after your app

Answer (score 2):

According to Places API Policies:

> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a map, that map must be provided by Google.
>
> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a page or view that does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by Google" logo with that data. For example, if your application displays a list of places on one tab, and a Google Map with those places on another tab, the first tab must show the "Powered by Google" logo.

So you can use Places autocomplete without a Google map, but in this case the logo is required.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies